# Using Joomla, how do I serve a different page to visitors from different countries?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I want a different homepage for different countries. For example, if the site is accessed from the USA then the home page should be different from when it is accessed from South Africa. I have to do this in Joomla 1.7.

Comment: this might be helpful to you http://www.siteground.com/joomla-hosting/joomla-extensions/ver1.5/jGeoIPFilter.htm

Comment: thank you mack..this works well

Comment: welcome nish, gujarati are nice people

Comment: And you are also a nice person...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This list of extensions might be useful:

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=geo&sa.x=0&sa.y=0

Comment: Thank you marcus i will try this extension..hope this will work